# Auto start an application using a script

Tags: mojave, bash

what I would like to do is a script which 1st checks whether a list of applications is running (e.g. Spotify, Thunderbird, Rocket Chat) and 2nd launch the apps from this list which are not already running. You could think of it like a "start all apps I typically use with one click/command".

I was reading up a little on launchd, but am not sure if this is what I want, as it sounds to me (at the moment) like an improved cron. Would a simple bash script suffice to do what I want? I'm currently running macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Welcome Sono. I think this might be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) : you have a problem X, thought of a possible solution Y and now are asking a question about Y rather than X. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Édouard, Does is really matter whether or not this is an XY Problem? Sono simply wants to know if a bash script would suffice, which of course it will and Allan provided an answer that's appropriate. So why even bring up the XY Problem well after it has been answered? (Rhetorical questions.)

Comment: @user3439894 It could lead to a better answer. It could help other people that have the same X problem. It would help people giving better answer.

Comment: Actually no, I don't think this is an XY Problem. Paragraph 1 states what I want to do. In Paragraph 2 I ask whether I could use bash and that I think that launchd is not what I want. Nevertheless I was also informed that I could use Apple Script for this. So in my book that is all fine and different methods were presented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you don't need to check to see if the app is running.  If it is, it will switch to it.

A very simple bash script will do this for you

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a Apps=( "Safari" "Firefox" "Mail" )

for i in "${Apps[@]}"
do
  open -a  "$i"
done
```

It's contains a simple array and will loop through each one and open the app if not running.  You can edit the array as needed with the names of each app in quotes separated by a space.

Save the file with a name you can remember like `openapps`.  Be sure to set the the "execute bit" `chmod +x openapps` and copy it to your Desktop or somewhere in your path (If it's on your Desktop, you can double click it to run).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064957/how-to-check-in-applescript-if-an-app-is-running-without-launching-it-via-osa) a list of solution to see if an app is running or not, something like:

```
set appName to "Safari"

if application appName is running then
    return "Running"
else
    return "Not running"
end if
```

2) Then, you can use this kind of applescript to open an app:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open application file "Spotify.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
end tell
```

3) Finally, you can save it into an `.command` and active it by a click or use terminal with `osascript /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/YOURSCRIPT.applescript` !

If you don't want to use terminal, you can use Automator to create a Mac Application that you can double click, add to the dock, etc.

1. Open `Automator` application
2. Choose "Application" type
3. Type "run" in the Actions search box
4. Double click "Run Shell Script"
5. Click the `Run` button in upper right corner to test it.
6. `File > Save` to create the Application.

[image]